# How do I specifically print out value from a specific dictionary from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
list= [{'Number': '501-1234564', 'Type': 'Life'},
       {'Number': 'GA123456', 'Type': 'Motor'},
       {'Number': '0012345', 'Type': 'Life'}]
```

I want to specifically extract the values from the second dictionary in the list, namely `GA123456` and `Motor`, how do i that?

Comment: `list[1].values()`
You better change the name (list is not good because of the data structure in built in Python with same name)

Comment: You should not use Python reserved words or built-in names (like `list`) as variable names.

Comment: 1) Do not name the variable `list` - its not a good idea since it is a data type in python. Lets call it `data_list`. `data_list` is a python list that you can access its elements using the index. so  `data_list[1]` should return the dict you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do it like this

```
list= [{'Number': '501-1234564', 'Type': 'Life'}, {'Number': 'GA123456', 'Type': 'Motor'},{'Number': '0012345', 'Type': 'Life'}]
```

You just need to access the list by its index so the dictionary you're trying to find is at `index 1`

```
print(list[1])
#Output {'Number': 'GA123456', 'Type': 'Motor'}
```

So once you done that you have the dictionary and you can now access keys by

```
list[1]["Number"]
#Output GA123456
```

You can also  do the `.get()` function. If you're curious about what other things you can do in a dictionary go ahead and do a `print(dir(list[1]))` or `print(dir(dict))`. This you will be able to see attributes and methods that can be used in a python dictionary.

```
list[1].get("Number")
```

Sample result

```
['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'items', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values']
```

Comment: `list[1]["Name"]` doesn't exist

Comment: Ohhh why did I typed that... anyways I'll edit that.. somethings that I do unexpectedly...